# Can I compress a file with image_magick and carrierwave gems?

Tags: carrierwave, minimagick

carrierwave with image_magick (and rmagick for that matter) provides methods such as resize_to_fit, etc.

Is there a method I can call to compress my images by, say, 50%?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to know is in the WIKI:
https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Specify-the-image-quality